# how to compare strings in two data frames in pandas(python 3.x)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two DFs like so:

```
df1:
ProjectCode        ProjectName
1                     project1
2                     project2
3                     projc3
4                     prj4
5                     prjct5
```

and df2 as

```
VillageName
v1
proj3
pro1
prjc3
project1
```

What I have to do is compare each `ProjectName` with `VillageName` and also add the percentage of matching. The percentage to be calculated as:

```
No. of matching characters/total characters * 100
```

The Village data i.e. df2 has more than 10 million records and the Project data i.e. df1 contains around 1200 records.

What I have done so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\distinctVillage.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\awcProjectMaster.xlsx")
for idx, row in df.iteritems():
    for idx1, row1 in df1.iteritems():
```

I don't know how to proceed with this. How to find substring and get third df having percentage match with each string. I think it is not feasible since each record from Project will have matching with each value of Village which will produce a huge result.

Is there any better way to find out which project names are matching with which village names and how good is the match?

Expected output:

```
ProjectName     VillageName      charactersMatching      PercentageMatch
project1         v1                   1                       whateverPercent
project1         proj3                4                        whateverPercent
```

The expected output can be changed depending on the feasibility and solution.

Comment: what is your expected output in the example provided?

Comment: Do you want to add 1200 columns to `df2` where each column is the match percentage with each word present in `df1`?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan yes that can be done.

Comment: no of records: 1394(projects) and 1305397(villages)

Comment: IN your expected output 1st row, the `1` character is a match, so why is the match percentage `0`? You need to explain more

Comment: ohh yes sorry you are right. We can also do like min. 4 characters should match or instead of characters we can use substring.

Answer (score 1):

The following code assumes you don't care about repeated characters (since it's taking the set on both sides).

```
percentage_match = df1['ProjectName'].apply(lambda x: df2['VillageName'].apply(lambda y: len(set(y).intersection(set(x))) / len(set(x+y))))
```

Output:

```
                    0         1         2         3         4
ProjectCode                                                  
1            0.111111  0.444444  0.500000  0.444444  1.000000
2            0.000000  0.444444  0.333333  0.444444  0.777778
3            0.000000  0.833333  0.428571  0.833333  0.555556
4            0.000000  0.500000  0.333333  0.500000  0.333333
5            0.000000  0.375000  0.250000  0.571429  0.555556
```

If you want the 'best match' for each Project:

```
percentage_match.idxmax(axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
1    4
2    4
3    1
4    1
5    3
```

Comment: ----> 1 percentage_match = df['ProjectName'].apply(lambda x: df1['VillageNameInEnglish'].apply(lambda y: len(set(y).intersection(set(x))) / len(set(x+y))))
      2 

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: sounds to me like you have nans in the data